# OpenStack Install - Not create openstack project

Tags: openstack, keystone, rdo

Installed manually openstack. 
It consist of controller, compute, storage in kvm(rhel7.3). 
and, refer to openstack manual (https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/install-guide-rdo/keystone-users.html) 
But, it alerted the error when create openstack project.

```
[root@test-controller ~]# openstack project create --domain default --description "Test Project" service
Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.
Could not determine a suitable URL for the plugin
```

I don't know why ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually there will be several parts that you could check for this issue.

1. When your OpenStack environment is installed, should be one stackrc file generated, which contains all necessary information used for openstack. Please check if you have this file and if information is correct, then please `source stackrc` file;
2. If the step 1 is good, please firstly check your keystone service is runnning;
3. Based on the info you shared, seems you did not create a service named keystone. Please follow the guide to setup all necessary resources, then begin to create project.

Notice: at the beginning, there is no user in the environment if you install every component manually. You have to use OpenStack documation step by step to create all resources. In all, you have to use admin token to create a service for keystone, create a project, then create a user, and add role to this user, then you could start your openstack travel.

Hope this could help you .

Answer (score 0):

This error message causes from different API version related keystone.
If your API version is 2? it's not correct, Domain feature is as of Version 3.

so you change your auth URL as follows

`export OS_AUTH_URL=http://YOUR_KEYSTONE_IP:5000/v3`

Answer (score 0):

it looks from your command that you have missed to export the authentical file, please check for the authentical file location and try command

```
source "authentical file"
```

and then run your command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your keystone service is not running. Please look at the controller is online or not & see whether the keystone is working or not. USE:

## openstack service list | grep keystone

OR

See keystone-api container is running or not. If not start the container & wait till it gets started & then try again.
OR

Use v3 as the keystone version because only v3 supports "Domains", not v2. So update the auth URL in your RC credential file & include v3 instead of v2.
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://YOUR_KEYSTONE_IP:5000/v3

Answer (score 0):

you have to first export your Authentication Data or try it as Admin user

Answer (score -1):

Try to install openstack as Devsatck or Packstack.
Source your openrc file which defines your host ip, passwords and service token.
your keystone service is not communicating to your database service.
https://www.tecmint.com/openstack-installation-guide-rhel-centos/